# Unable to render table on GitHub Readme

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

```
| Reference        | Contract          | 
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| EIP-20 Token      | 0x4c7507262dA41A5A96ae3F836D602d74Eb10A6d0 | 
| Uniswap V2     | 0x35775d560e7e0370259c69475c44dbe5cf183afa     |  
| Uniswap V3 |  0xa00822c70f9ba29d74d92207c798c0d9cad3735e   |
```

This is my code for Readme table. It is working on VSC with a Markdown Preview and here on Stack Overflow:

| Reference | Contract |
| --- | --- |
| EIP-20 Token | 0x4c7507262dA41A5A96ae3F836D602d74Eb10A6d0 |
| Uniswap V2 | 0x35775d560e7e0370259c69475c44dbe5cf183afa |
| Uniswap V3 | 0xa00822c70f9ba29d74d92207c798c0d9cad3735e |

but not working well on GitHub.

Comment: How many columns does it have? One possible problem would be more obvious if you aligned them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspect @jonrsharpe alludes, you have a syntactical error. Your delimiter row (second line) specifies three columns. However, your header row (line 1) and data rows (lines 3 and 4) have just two columns. See [GitHub Flavored Markdown, Tables](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-).

Remove the extraneous third column from your header specification (line 2) like this:

```
| Reference        | Contract          | 
| ------------- |:-------------:|
| EIP-20 Token      | 0x4c7507262dA41A5A96ae3F836D602d74Eb10A6d0 | 
| Uniswap V2     | 0x35775d560e7e0370259c69475c44dbe5cf183afa     |  
| Uniswap V3 |  0xa00822c70f9ba29d74d92207c798c0d9cad3735e   |
```